# Docker (Compose? Swarm?) How to run a health check before exposing cotainer

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I have a web app (netcore) running in a docker container. If I update it under load it won't be able to handle requests until there is a gap. This might be a bug in my app, or in the .net, I am looking for a workaround for now. If I hit the app with a single http request before exposing it to the traffic though, it works as expected.

I would like to get this behaviour:

1. In the running server get the latest release of the container.
2. Launch the container detached from network.
3. Run a health check on it, if health check fails - stop.
4. Remove old container.
5. Attach new container and start processing traffic.

I am using compose atm, and have somewhat limited knowledge of docker infrastructure and the problem should be something well understood, yet I've failed finding anything in the google on the topic.

It kind of sounds like Kubernetees at this stage, but I would like to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: That in fact sounds very close to out-of-the-box Kubernetes Deployment/Service behavior.  Standalone Docker doesn't come with this capability built in; you'd have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I was looking for is the Blue/Green deployment and it is quite easy to search for it.

E.g.

https://github.com/Sinkler/docker-nginx-blue-green

https://coderbook.com/@marcus/how-to-do-zero-downtime-deployments-of-docker-containers/

Swarm has a feature which could be useful as well: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/